# Sqlite: replacing or updating a row only if it is changed

Tags: ios, sqlite, insert-update

An Objective-C iOS app integrates a sqlite with a set of rows, each identified by an ID. For example:

```
| id | user_name |  age   |
------------------------------
|  1 |   johnny  |  33    |
|  2 |    mark   |  30    |
|  3 |  maroccia |  50    |
```

Asynchronously, the app receives the same set of records, but some of them are modified: it has to update (or replace) only the modified records, ignoring the other ones (those not modified).

For example, the app receives such updated rows:

```
| id | user_name |  age   |
------------------------------
|  1 |   johnny  |  33    |
|  2 |    mark   |  30    |
|  3 |  ballarin |  50    |  <------ CHANGED RECORD
```

In this case, only the third record is changed and the app should update or replace just it, ignoring the first two. 
Obviously, the INSERT OR REPLACE does not suit me because it will write all the records. So, there exists some procedure in sqlite (or Objective-C) which can help me, updating only the modified records?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could simply replace all rows; the result is the same.

If you do not want to rewrite rows that have not actually changed, you have to compare all column values. If you have both the old rows and the received rows in separate tables, you can compare entire rows with a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO MyData
SELECT * FROM ReceivedData
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM MyData;
```

Comment: replacing all row requires too many resources. Is there some shortcut useful for comparing all column values if I don't have a separate table for received rows? I'm working with Objective-c and I receive the rows in JSON format

Comment: JSON is not SQL. You can simply compare the rows one by one.